# Pytables NumExpr ValueError: too many inputs when querying with a lot of conditions

Tags: python, pytables, numexpr

I encounter this error when querying a pytables table with where method passing a string with 50 conditions. These conditions are basically a translation of a SQL IN clause i.e. I want to get records where a particular field is equal to a certain list of values.

```
C:\Python2764\lib\site-packages\numexpr\necompiler.pyc in evaluate(ex, local_dict, global_dict, out, order, casting, **kwargs)
    744     kwargs = {'out': out, 'order': order, 'casting': casting,
    745               'ex_uses_vml': ex_uses_vml}
--> 746     return compiled_ex(*arguments, **kwargs)

ValueError: too many inputs
```

What would be another way to perform the same query? My first thought is to perform the query 50 times, once for each value and merge the results. I was hoping maybe there is a more elegant solution to this.

Is there a known restriction on the number of conditions that can be passed to numexpr?

Comment: I have only one condition in my queries, and I still get the same error.

Answer (score 3):

If you use `pandas.DataFrame.query` then you can try to change `engine='python'` in **kwargs.

Answer (score 2):

I asked the same question to the Pytable guys on GitHub. (Coincidentally, I had 50 conditions translated from a SQL IN clause as well.) They were really nice and fast to respond. It is a numpy issue:

> This is a limitation of numexpr based on the NPY_MAXARGS value which
>   is defined in numpy. Upgrading to numpy v1.8 may fix the issue. See
>   [numpy/numpy#226](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/pull/226) and `[1]`.
>   ...
>   ...
>   Oh and by the way, the limit is `NPY_MAXARGS=32`

What numpy version do you use? numpy 1.8 is OK.

EDIT: Actually it's not working on numpy 1.8 as well. They have NPY_MAXARGS=32 still

Comment: Is it possible to increase the value of `NPY_MAXARGS` or it is hard-coded in the `numpy` source code?